# Lua Compare two Tables values No Order

Tags: performance, lua, lua-table

I wonder if there is a faster way to check if two tables are equal (without order in the keys).

This is my solution

```
function TableCompareNoOrder(table1,table2)
    if #table1 ~= #table2 then return false end
    local equal = false
    for key, item in pairs(table1) do
        for key2, item2 in pairs(table2) do
            if item == item2 then equal = true end
        end 
        if equal == false then return false end
    end
    local equal = false
    for key, item in pairs(table2) do
        for key2, item2 in pairs(table1) do
            if item == item2 then equal = true end
        end 
        if equal == false then return false end
    end

    return equal
end


a = {1,2,3,0}
b = {2,3,1,0}
print(TableCompareNoOrder(a,b))
```

Comment: Sorting will be faster

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to check if two tables have the same key-value pairs, or do you want to check if two sequences have the same set of elements?

Comment: luther: The code IMO makes it apparent that the latter is desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are faster ways. Your approach is currently O(n²) as it has to compare each element with each other element. One way is to sort the arrays first. Another one would be to build a lookup table ("set") using the hash part. If hash access is assumed to take amortized constant time, this should run in **O(n)** time - significantly faster. It will take O(n) additional memory but leaves the passed tables intact; to do the same using sorting you'd have to first create a copy, then sort it.

The hash approach looks like the following (and also works for values like tables which are compared by reference and can't be sorted unless a metatable is set or a custom comparator function is supplied):

```lua
function TableCompareNoOrder(table1, table2)
    if #table1 ~= #table2 then return false end
    -- Consider an early "return true" if table1 == table2 here
    local t1_counts = {}
    -- Check if the same elements occur the same number of times
    for _, v1 in ipairs(table1) do
        t1_counts[v1] = (t1_counts[v1] or 0) + 1
    end
    for _, v2 in ipairs(table2) do
        local count = t1_counts[v2] or 0
        if count == 0 then return false end
        t1_counts[v2] = count - 1
    end
    return true
end
```

For the sake of completeness, here's a simple implementation using sorting:

```lua
function TableCompareNoOrder(table1, table2)
    if #table1 ~= #table2 then return false end
    -- Lazy implementation: Sort copies of both tables instead of using a binary search. Takes twice as much memory.
    local t1_sorted = {table.unpack(table1)} -- simple way to copy the table, limited by stack size
    table.sort(t1_sorted)
    local t2_sorted = {table.unpack(table2)}
    table.sort(t2_sorted)
    for i, v1 in ipairs(t1_sorted) do
        if t2_sorted[i] ~= v1 then return false end
    end
    return true
end
```

This should roughly run in **O(n log n)** (performance is determined by the sorting algorithm, usually quicksort which has this as it's average running time).

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked here, although I cant always use table.sort. Because I am using in reaper scripts and have some types that cant go in there else it crash. Thanks a lot for the complete answer.